# IntelliJ IDEA woes after dirty reboot

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, intellij-idea, webstorm

I am experiencing troubles on IntelliJ IDEA (both 2018.1.1 and older 2017.x) after an unexpected reboot of my machine occurred while I was working on several projects (an Angular CLI project and two Java projects):

1) When I tried to reopen the Angular project, its main IntelliJ module was not recognized anymore. ng serve does not seem to detect file changes anymore. I have to CTRL+C it to force the refresh. This happens every time I quit IntelliJ and reopen it.

2) Two Spring boot Maven project need to be re-registered every time they get reopened. I am not able to register a working Run configuration until I run the AFAIK obsolete `mvn idea:idea` command, and even then I cannot run it as a Spring boot project, but only as a normal project.

I've tried the following (not in this order):

1) Delete every project-related IntelliJ IDEA file and directory (*.iml, .idea)

2) Delete IDEA profile

3) Delete and reinstall IDEA (upgrading from 2017.x to 2018.1.1 in the process).

4) Invalidate cache.

to no avail.

Do you have any suggestion? 
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried reimporting the projects?

Comment: This sound like something best suited for IntelliJ support.

Comment: @ChristophS Yes, no change.

Comment: @Thihara You are right, but I don't have an error trace or anything I can give them, apart from telling "Hey, it used to work, it doesn't anymore". For this reason I am asking for suggestions here on S.O.

Comment: You may want to try the `File | Invalidate Caches / Restart...` menu item. (Note that this will also remove your local history when used)

Comment: @BasLeijdekkers I forgot to add to the list that I already tried that also. Thank you